# Node colors change after building (texmaker pdf and real pdf looks different)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes, backgrounds

I have tried (my own way) to make the example in the TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 2.10 (p. 68).
When I build this code, the pdf-file does not look identical to the PDF viewer in texmaker. What can I do to fix this problem?
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage[top=0.2cm, bottom=0.2cm, left=0.2cm, right=0.2cm]{geometry}
\paperheight = 100pt
\paperwidth = 500pt
%\pagecolor{yellow!85!green!15}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm,
nonterminal/.style={rectangle, minimum size=6mm, very thick, draw=red!50!black!50, % 50% red 
top color=white, bottom color=red!50!black!20, font=\itshape},
terminal/.style={rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm, very thick,draw=black!50,
top color=white,bottom color=black!20, font=\ttfamily},
point/.style={coordinate},>=stealth',thick,draw=black!50,]

\node [point]at (-3,0) (one) {};
\node [nonterminal]at (-1,0) (US1) {unsigned integer};

\node [point]at (0.6,0) (two) {};
\node [terminal]at (1.5,0) (dot) {.};

\node [point]at (0.85,0) (three) {};
\node [terminal]at (3,0) (DI) {digit};

\node [point]at (3.8,0) (four) {};
\node [point]at (4,0) (five) {};
\node [point]at (4.3,0) (six) {};
\node [terminal]at (5,0) (E) {E};

\node [point]at (5.5,-1.5) (low) {};
\node [point]at (11,-1.5) (long) {};

\node [point]at (3,-1) (low1) {};
\node [point]at (2,0) (middel) {};

\node [point]at (3.6,1) (high1) {};
\node [point]at (1.5,1) (short) {};

\node [point]at (8,0) (seven) {};
\node [terminal]at (6.5,1) (plus) {+};
\node [terminal]at (6.5,-1) (minus) {-};
\node [nonterminal]at (10,0) (US2) {unsigned integer};
\node [point]at (12,0) (eleven) {};
\node [point]at (12.5,0) (twelve) {};

\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (one) -- (US1);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (US1) -- (dot);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (dot) -- (DI);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (DI) -- (E);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (E) -- (US2);

\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (E) |- (plus);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (E) |- (minus);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (plus) -| (seven);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (minus) -| (seven);

\draw [<-,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (middel) |- (low1); 
\draw [very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (low1) -| (four);

\draw [very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (two) |- (short); 
\draw [very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (short) -- (high1);
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (high1) -| (five); 

\draw [very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (six) |- (low); 
\draw [very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (low) -- (long); 
\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20,rounded corners=3mm] (long) -| (eleven); 

\draw [->,very thick,color=black!20] (US2) -- (twelve);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you tested with different pdf viewers? I've tested your code on [writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/read/tpcrzfnzxtwj) and looks correct in its viewer and Adobe Reader.

Comment: Can you also put `\listfiles` in your preamble and paste the package list in your `.log` file for version check?

Comment: I've tested it and it works for me as well. I agree with @percusse that you might have something outdated.

Comment: @JakobHP did you manage to resolve this? I cannot reproduce the issue on my system either.